# Android: Use the facebook app to login to instead of the mobile login page

Tags: java, android

I developed a mobile app by turning the mobile site into a webview. What I would like to do is have the end user utilize the facebook app to register & login instead of being directed to the mobile login page. Is it possible to do this on webview?

Here is what my code looks like so far. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
package com.chilindo.chilindo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebView.loadUrl("http://chilindo.com/register.aspx");

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    //@Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        }

        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a facebook app on this page (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/)  &  Use facebook SDK to intergrate app https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/

Comment: Hi, I've create a facebook app, but how would I integrate it when I already have a webview. Can you provide me with some guidance or instruction please?

Comment: follow these instructions  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android     let me know if you face any problem following  instructions

Comment: you have to add  facebook login button outside of webview

Comment: Will the webview (page in javascript) be able to use the api token to log them into the page?

Comment: I never done that but in theory I think you can use that api token to login using Javascript

Comment: How would I do that?